# strophe.js not calling disconnect when user same user logged in multiple times

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I'm new to strophe.js. I'm developing one website for video calling I used following things -
**strophe.js version 1.0.2 with BOSH , xmpp(ejabbered) version 2.1.11**.

Now i'm

> logging with same user multiple times with different browsers or
>   devices but it is not calling disconnect method asyncronously

. I'm searching for this but not getting what need to be done for this kind of situation where **i can limit single login for single user**.

Can anyone help me out for solving my issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is normal for xmpp. As each user can have several resources.

If the resource is always the same one, you can try [this](http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#auth):

> The option resource_conflict defines the action when a client attempts
>   to login to an account with a resource that is already connected. The
>   option syntax is:
>
> resource_conflict: setresource|closenew|closeold The possible values
>   match exactly the three possibilities described in XMPP Core: section
>   7.7.2.2. The default value is closeold. If the client uses old Jabber Non-SASL authentication (XEP-0078), then this option is not respected,
>   and the action performed is closeold.

If the configure above doesn't work, please also give a try of [this](http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#saslanonymous):

If you just want to limit the login times for the same user:

> The anonymous authentication method can be configured with the
>   following options. Remember that you can use the host_config option to
>   set virtual host specific options (see section 3.1.3).
>
> allow_multiple_connections: false|true This option is only used when
>   the anonymous mode is enabled. Setting it to true means that the same
>   username can be taken multiple times in anonymous login mode if
>   different resource are used to connect. This option is only useful in
>   very special occasions. The default value is false.